# how to pass value to function with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I would like to get ajax return value. please help my code does not return value false or true.

I have two functions in this script validate() which calling validateDate() which ajax is present

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){

    function validateDate(date) {

    return $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>activate/checkdate",
            data: "Date_of_Birth="+date,
            success: function(msg){
                if(msg=="false"){
                       return false;
                 }
                else{
                       return false;
                }
             }
         });
     }

 function validatesa() {
     var date = $("#Datepicker").val();
     if (validateDate(date)) {
      return true;
      } else {
      sweetAlert( date , "is not a valid date YYYY-MM-DD", "error");
     return false;
       } 
     }
   }else {
      sweetAlert( date , "is not a valid date YYYY-MM-DD", "error");
       return false;
      } 
  }
     $("form").bind("submit", validatesa);

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAX is asynchronous process so return not allowed. In your case you have to use `async : false`  in your ajax request option. ad have to use return variable. So your function code should be.

```
function validateDate(date) {
    var response="";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>activate/checkdate",
        async: false,
        data: {
            Date_of_Birth:  date
        },
        success: function(msg) {
            if (msg == "false") {
                response =  false;
            } else {
                response =  true;
            }
        }
    });
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the explanation. it helps a lot. A change some on the script with comment thanks a lot

```
 function validateDate(date) {
   var response="";   // i assign as empty first since ajax success dont have value yet
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>activate/checkdate",
    async: false,
    data: {
        Date_of_Birth:  date
    },
    success: function(msg) {
        if (msg == "false") {
            response =  false; // assign false to response variable since false is the output.
        } else {
            response =  true;
        }
      }
   });
   return response;
 }
```